# Difference between enabled, isActiveAndEnabled and activeInHierarchy in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot believe that this question has not already been asked somewhere; a fairly thorough Googling has turned up no results.  The Unity documentation says this about the [`Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-isActiveAndEnabled.html) field:

> Has the Behaviour had enabled called.
>   True while the behaviour is enabled, false when disabled.

And it says this about [`Behaviour.enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html):

> Enabled Behaviours are Updated, disabled Behaviours are not.
>   This is shown as the small checkbox in the inspector of the behaviour.

So one article just elaborates on what "Enabled" means more than the other.  As far as I can tell, these fields are true/false under the exact same conditions!   So what is the difference?  When would you use one over the other?  A clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`isActiveAndEnabled` and `enabled` seems very confusing to beginners and I bet most people still don't know the difference and when to use each one. I was one of these people.

Two things to understand:

*A*.GameObjects can be *activated* and *de-activated*.

*B*.Scripts can be *enabled* and *disabled*.

The keyword in `isActiveAndEnabled` should explains it all.

What happens with each property:

**1**.For `Behaviour.enabled`, this is the truth table:

- GameObject = *Active* AND Script = *Enabled* then Behaviour.enabled =
  true.
- GameObject = *Active* AND Script = *Disabled* then Behaviour.enabled =
  false.
- GameObject = *Inactive* AND Script = *Enabled* then Behaviour.enabled =
  true.
- GameObject = *Inactive* AND Script = *Disabled* then Behaviour.enabled =
  false.

It **doesn't** matter if the `GameObject` the script is attached to is *activated* or *deactivated* for `Behaviour.enabled` to return *true*. What matters is if the script or component that is attached to the GameObject is enabled or disabled.

**2**.For `Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled`, this is the truth table:

- GameObject = *Active* AND Script = *Enabled* then isActiveAndEnabled =
  true.
- GameObject = *Active* AND Script = *Disabled* then isActiveAndEnabled =
  false.
- GameObject = *Inactive* AND Script = *Enabled* then isActiveAndEnabled =
  false.
- GameObject = *Inactive* AND Script = *Disabled* then isActiveAndEnabled =
  false.

It **matters** if `GameObject` is enabled or disabled for `Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled` to return true or false. In order for `Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled` to return `true`, *both* the GameObject the script/component is attached to  must be *active* and the script must be *enabled*. If any of this is false, then `Behaviour.isActiveAndEnabled` will return `false`.

**EDIT**:

> When would you want to get `enabled` and NOT `isActiveAndEnabled`?

You use `enabled` to check if a script is enable/disabled. You can also use it to enable or disable a script. Depending on your Game logic, there are times when you disable/enable a script. For example when a GameObject is no longer visible on the screen but you have one script attached to it that is doing heavy calculation in the `Update()` function, you can disable that script with enabled and enable it back later on when the GameObject is visible.

`isActiveAndEnabled` is read only. You can only use it to check if *both* the script is `enabled` and the **GameObject** it is attached to `active`.  You *cannot* use it to enable or activate the GameObject.

`if (myScriptInstance.isActiveAndEnabled)` is a short hand for `if (myScriptInstance.gameObject.activeSelf && myScriptInstance.enabled)` but `isActiveAndEnabled` makes your code shorter and easier to read.

> Between GameObject.activeInHierarchy and Behaviour.enabled, one has
>   all the information one needs to check state.

Not really. These are very different variables you will definitely need when using Unity. I don't think you understand what `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` is used for. To check if GameObject is active or not, use `GameObject.activeSelf` not `GameObject.activeInHierarchy`. To activate/deactivate GameObject use `GameObject.SetActive(true/false);`

**3**.**GameObject.activeInHierarchy and when to use it**:

For the table below, *pObj = Parent GameObject* and *cObj = Child GameObject* and that GameObject.activeInHierarchy is being performed on the Child GameObject.

- pObj = *Active* AND cObj = *Active* then GameObject.activeInHierarchy =
  true.
- pObj = *Active* AND cObj = *Inactive* then GameObject.activeInHierarchy =
  false.
- pObj = *Inactive* AND cObj = *Active* then GameObject.activeInHierarchy =
  false.
- pObj = *Inactive* AND cObj = *Inactive* then `GameObject.activeInHierarchy =
  false.

`GameObject.activeInHierarchy` is almost like `isActiveAndEnabled`. It depends on two things for it to be `true`. The parent GameObject must be active. The GameObject(Child) the check is being performed on must also be active. If any of this is false, then `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` will return `false`.

You use `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` to check if the provided GameObject is active and the-same time to check if all of its parents are active too. If the GameObject does not have parent then simply use `GameObject.activeSelf`. `GameObject.activeSelf` will only check if the GameObject is active or not. It won't check the parent like `GameObject.activeInHierarchy`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!  That's pretty much how I figured it worked, I just don't understand why Unity has this field.  Between `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` and `Behaviour.enabled`, one has all the information one needs to check state.  I guess `isActiveAndEnabled` is shorter/cleaner, but what they gained in syntactic sugar I feel like they lost in API clarity...

Comment: I guess my question now is, when would you want to get `enabled` and NOT `isActiveAndEnabled`?  Seems like `enabled` should only be used for setting, not getting.

Comment: Before I answer that, I have a question for you. Do you know the difference between GameObject and Script/Component?

Comment: Lol yes.  Don't know how I would convince u of that, but I've written several thousand lines of C# code in managed plugins so yes I'm pretty hip to the difference :P you attach Components to GameObjects

Comment: Lol I feel horrible for asking that but I just wanted to make sure you are not new to Unity and understood both. I will edit my answer to answer that.

Comment: "if (myScriptInstance.isActiveAndEnabled) is a short hand for if (myScriptInstance.gameObject.activeSelf && myScriptInstance.enabled)" is wrong! It would be (myScriptInstance.gameObject.activeInHierarchy && myScriptInstance.enabled)! Also last chapter should mention that isActiveAndEnabled also takes hierarchy into account like activeInHierarchy.

Answer (score 11):

I know it is misleading:

> GameObject.active**Self** = Is the game object active regardless of its parents

We expect a game object to be active when its whole hierarchy is active. But `activeSelf` tells us whether or not that particular game object is active, and ignores the active status of the parents.

> GameObject.active**InHierarchy** = Is the game object (and all its parents) actually active and therefore updating

---

> Behaviour.isActive**And**Enabled = Has the Behaviour had enabled called.

In order for a behaviour to has enabled called, its game object (and all its parents) must be active AND the behaviour itself must be enabled.

> Behaviour.enabled = Enabled Behaviours are Updated

In order for a behaviour to be updated, the checkbox must be checked. however, if the game object (or one of its parents) isn't active then it cannot be updated so its attached behaviours cannot be updated.

---

### So in short:

---

Behaviour.**isActiveAndEnabled:** *component is enabled & **game object hierarchy is active***

Behaviour.**enabled:** *component is enabled & **game object hierarchy may be active or deactivated***

---

GameObject.**activeSelf:** *game object is active, **its parents may not***

GameObject.**activeInHierarchy:** *game object **and all its parents** are active*

---

Comment: isActiveAndEnabled also returns false if gameObject is not active in hierarchy (activeSelf is true but parent activeSelf is false)! This table makes it seem it only checks for activeSelf and not parent state when comparing to activeInHierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers, IsActiveAndEnabled seems to check whether GameObject is active in its hierarchy (like IsActiveInHierarchy), not just if that GameObject is active (like activeSelf). This is not written in Unity documentation. Below is a truth table for all states.

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| Component.enabled | GameObject.activeSelf | Parent GameObject.activeSelf | GameObject ActiveInHierarchy | Component isActiveAndEnabled |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| TRUE              | TRUE                  | TRUE                         | TRUE                         | TRUE                         |
| FALSE             | TRUE                  | TRUE                         | TRUE                         | FALSE                        |
| TRUE              | FALSE                 | TRUE                         | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
| FALSE             | FALSE                 | TRUE                         | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
| TRUE              | TRUE                  | FALSE                        | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
| FALSE             | TRUE                  | FALSE                        | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
| TRUE              | FALSE                 | FALSE                        | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
| FALSE             | FALSE                 | FALSE                        | FALSE                        | FALSE                        |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed isActiveAndEnabled is false when Awake event wasn't called.

Comment: Your script must be disabled or attached to a GameObject that is inactive (or  the child, grandchild, etc of an inactive GameObject). `isActiveAndEnabled` has nothing to do with whether `Awake()` has been called